# Browsers Rendering Differently

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I'm having trouble getting Safari and Firefox to render my CSS like it happens in Chrome and Webkit.

I'm building a website that shows some pictures and when any of them is clicked, some text and thumbs rollout from behind that picture.

I'm using CSS transition by changing the class of a parent object to move some child nodes, but i'm sure that is no the problem.

[Here you can try and see how it works.](https://site1376060724.websiteseguro.com/new/retorna_meio2.php)
Try resize the page to see how it reacts....

As seen in Chrome/Webkit, even after the div is "open" it respects the total width of the page, the side text is also never higher than the image on the left and the thumbs on the bottom are always just above the image.

When in Safari or Firefox, these behaviors are not rendered. I tried some "  !important  " rules and "RESET.CSS" but i just can't find a way to make it render the same way on every browser.

I'm trying to only use Javascript when there is no more options...

Does anyone have a clue?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, a fixed…

Mysteriously the solution was:

```
.cont_texto{
    display: block;
    height: 0;
}
```

Weird

Answer (score 0):

```
.cont_foto img { width: 100% !important; }
```

If I understand you correctly, that should get you closer to where you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've just updatted the document with your idea, but i see no difference.

Comment: Sorry, it's late .cont_foto img { width: 100% !important; }

Comment: In did it worked, but i still can't get the text to scroll on the side div

Comment: It looks good to me. I'm using FF, Safari and Chrome on a mac.